# TextWatcher not working, what is wrong

Tags: android, listener, textwatcher

The implementation of TextWatcher in the onCreate method is not working, I tried doing text typing using virtual keyboard and hardware keyboard present, also tried the code on emulator and real device. nothing seems to work.

i even renamed the EditTexts in the layout and clean the project, re-build it, no hope

any idea?

here is the code

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.remarks);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    Intent i = getIntent();
    Current_Language = i.getStringExtra("Lang");
    Q1Rate = i.getFloatExtra("Q1Rate", 0f);
    Q2Rate = i.getFloatExtra("Q2Rate", 0f);
    Q3Rate = i.getFloatExtra("Q3Rate", 0f);
    Q4Rate = i.getFloatExtra("Q4Rate", 0f);
    Q5Rate = i.getFloatExtra("Q5Rate", 0f);
    LoadSettings();
    NextBtnState();
    final EditText edt_PhoneNo     = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_Remarks_PhoneNo);
    final EditText edt_Suggestions = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_Remarks_Suggestion);
    edt_Suggestions.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        }
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            ShowToast("I Am Here Firas");
            resetTimeout();
        }
    });
    edt_PhoneNo.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        }
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            ShowToast("I Am Here Firas");
            resetTimeout();
        }
    });
}
```

here is my ShowToast

```
public void ShowToast (String Msg) {
    Context context = getApplicationContext();
    CharSequence text = Msg;
    int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
    toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER|Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
    toast.show();
}
```

and here is the layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/Azure1"
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<GridLayout
    android:id="@+id/Grid1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:columnCount="4"
    android:rowCount="4" >

    <Space
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_ClientLogo"
        android:layout_width="275dp"
        android:layout_height="145dp"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:src="@drawable/general_client_logo" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_CustomerSatisfactionSurvey"
        android:layout_width="948dp"
        android:layout_height="103dp"
        android:layout_column="3"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/Customer_Satisfaction_Survey"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="@color/OrangeRed2"
        android:textSize="50sp" />
</GridLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/ly_Stars"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="379dp">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edt_Remarks_PhoneNo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tv_Remarks_PhoneNo"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/Mobile_No"
        android:inputType="phone" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_Remarks_Suggestions"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/edt_Remarks_PhoneNo"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:text="@string/Any_Comment"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edt_Remarks_Suggestion"
        android:layout_width="590dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tv_Remarks_Suggestions"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/suggestion"
        android:inputType="textCapSentences|textMultiLine"
        android:singleLine="false" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_Remarks_PhoneNo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/Phone_Account_No"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/ly_NextPrevios"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="bottom" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_Next"
        style="@style/ButtonText"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/tv_PoweredBy"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="45dp"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_blue"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/arrow_right"
        android:onClick="Next_Page"
        android:text="@string/btn_Next" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_PoweredBy"
        android:layout_width="772dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/powerd_by_prime"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_Previous"
        style="@style/ButtonText"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/tv_PoweredBy"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="45dp"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_blue"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/arrow_left"
        android:onClick="Previous_Page"
        android:text="@string/btn_Previous" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_help"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btn_Previous"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:onClick="ShowHelpDialog"
        android:src="@drawable/help_64" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_Steps"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/progressBar1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:text="@string/Step6of6"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="650dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/img_help"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:max="6"
        android:progress="6"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/my_progress" />

</RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: And where is your `ShowToast()` function?

Comment: How does it "not work"? What have you tried? Are you seeing errors or do the toasts not show? What does your ShowToast method look like? Have you tried printing Log statements? What happens if you move the toast/log and resetTimeout call to onTextChanged?

Comment: I added the ShowToast

Comment: no errors, just nothing happens, no toast

Comment: Can you also post the remarks layout file?

Comment: Have you tried printing Log statements? What happens if you move the toast/log and resetTimeout call to onTextChanged?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The naming of the EditText was conflicting with another layout so
I renamed the EditTexts in both the layouts and then cleaned the project, 
everything works now.
Google must do something about the conflict of the naming of Views on different layouts

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the context from getApplicationContext() to ActivityName.this